# SSHing via WSL2 into remote debian vm results in "overriding" reverse search

Tags: terminal, prompt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When using WSL2 to SSH into a remote debian VM the reverse search behaves strange, eg. when searching for `gitlab` with `dpkg -l | grep gitlab` in history.

Behaviour:

```
(reverse-i-search)`gitlabkg -l | grep gitlab
```

Expected behaviour (**working with putty**):

```
(reverse-i-search)`gitlab': dpkg -l | grep gitlab
```

I am using zsh in WSL2, but `/bin/bash`ing before the SSH connection results in the same behaviour.

Interesting is that the starting quote of the search is a backtick while the closing one is a single tick.

`locale` output of WSL2 is equal to VM:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

VMs with `$TERM` value of `xterm-color` experience the problem while VMs with `xterm-256color` work fine. WSL2 also uses `xterm-256color`.
I tried to `export TERM=xterm-color` before SSHing, which results in no change.